# How to disable and enable all widgets in a python tkinter frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, frame

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import mysql.connector
from tkinter import messagebox

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="")
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS STUDENT_RECORDS")
mycursor.execute("USE STUDENT_RECORDS")
mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS STU (ROLL_NO INT, NAME VARCHAR(255), EMAIL VARCHAR(255), GENDER VARCHAR(255), CONTACT VARCHAR(255), DOB VARCHAR(255), ADDRESS VARCHAR(255))")

class Students:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Student Management System")
        self.root.geometry("1350x700+0+0")
        color = "blue"

        title = Label(self.root, text="Student Management System", bd=10, relief=GROOVE, font=("times new roman", 40, "bold"), bg="yellow", fg="red")
        title.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

#=================All Variables
        self.Roll_no_var = StringVar()
        self.name_var = StringVar()
        self.email_var = StringVar()
        self.gender_var = StringVar()
        self.contact_var = StringVar()
        self.dob_var = StringVar()

        self.searchby_var = StringVar()
        self.searchtxt_var = StringVar()


#=================MANAGE FRAME
        self.Manage_Frame = Frame(self.root, bd=4, relief=RIDGE, bg=color)
        self.Manage_Frame.place(x=20,y=100,width=450,height=600)

        m_title = Label(self.Manage_Frame, text="Manage Students", bd=10, font=("times new roman", 30, "bold"), bg=color, fg="white")
        m_title.grid(row=0,columnspan=2,pady=20)

        lbl_roll = Label(self.Manage_Frame, text="ROLL NO.", font=("times new roman", 20, "bold"), bg=color, fg="white")
        lbl_roll.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        txt_roll = Entry(self.Manage_Frame, textvariable=self.Roll_no_var, font=("times new roman", 15, "bold"), bd=5, relief=GROOVE)
        txt_roll.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        lbl_name = Label(self.Manage_Frame, text="Name", font=("times new roman", 20, "bold"), bg=color, fg="white")
        lbl_name.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")
        print(type(lbl_name))
        txt_name = Entry(self.Manage_Frame, textvariable=self.name_var, font=("times new roman", 15, "bold"), bd=5, relief=GROOVE)
        txt_name.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        lbl_Email = Label(self.Manage_Frame, text="Email", font=("times new roman", 20, "bold"), bg=color, fg="white")
        lbl_Email.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        txt_Email = Entry(self.Manage_Frame, textvariable=self.email_var, font=("times new roman", 15, "bold"), bd=5, relief=GROOVE)
        txt_Email.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        lbl_gender = Label(self.Manage_Frame, text="Gender", font=("times new roman", 20, "bold"), bg=color, fg="white")
        lbl_gender.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        combo_gender = ttk.Combobox(self.Manage_Frame, textvariable=self.gender_var, font=("times new roman", 13, "bold"), state="readonly")
        combo_gender['values']=("Male", "Female", "Other")
        combo_gender.grid(row=4, column=1, pady=10, padx=20)

        lbl_contact = Label(self.Manage_Frame, text="Contact", font=("times new roman", 20, "bold"), bg=color, fg="white")
        lbl_contact.grid(row=5, column=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        txt_contact = Entry(self.Manage_Frame, textvariable=self.contact_var, font=("times new roman", 15, "bold"), bd=5, relief=GROOVE)
        txt_contact.grid(row=5, column=1, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        lbl_dob = Label(self.Manage_Frame, text="D.O.B", font=("times new roman", 20, "bold"), bg=color, fg="white")
        lbl_dob.grid(row=6, column=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        txt_dob = Entry(self.Manage_Frame, textvariable=self.dob_var, font=("times new roman", 15, "bold"), bd=5, relief=GROOVE)
        txt_dob.grid(row=6, column=1, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        lbl_address = Label(self.Manage_Frame, text="Address", font=("times new roman", 20, "bold"), bg=color, fg="white")
        lbl_address.grid(row=7, column=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        self.txt_address = Text(self.Manage_Frame, font=("", 10, "bold"), height=4, width=30)
        self.txt_address.grid(row=7, column=1, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

#=================BUTTON FRAME
        btn_Frame = Frame(self.Manage_Frame, bd=4, relief=RIDGE, bg=color)
        btn_Frame.place(x=18,y=540,width=420)

        add_btn = Button(btn_Frame, text="ADD", width=10).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
        update_btn = Button(btn_Frame, text="UPDATE", width=10).grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)
        delete_btn = Button(btn_Frame, text="DELETE", width=10).grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=5)
        clear_btn = Button(btn_Frame, text="CLEAR", width=10).grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=5)

#==================ON OFF BUTTON FRAME
        on_off_btn_Frame = Frame(self.root, bd=4, relief=RIDGE, bg='red')
        on_off_btn_Frame.place(x=1305,y=100,width=55, height=70)

        on_btn = Button(on_off_btn_Frame, text='ON', command=self.on_all).pack(fill=X, side=TOP)
        off_btn = Button(on_off_btn_Frame, text='OFF', command=self.off_all).pack(fill=X, side=BOTTOM)

#=================TABLE FRAME
        Table_Frame = Frame(self.root, bd=4, relief=RIDGE, bg="crimson")
        Table_Frame.place(x=500,y=110, width=760, height=500)

        scrollx = Scrollbar(Table_Frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        scrolly = Scrollbar(Table_Frame, orient=VERTICAL)
        self.Student_table = ttk.Treeview(Table_Frame, columns=("Roll", "Name", "Email", "Gender", "Contact", "dob", "Address"), xscrollcommand=scrollx.set, yscrollcommand=scrolly.set)
        scrollx.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        scrolly.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        scrollx.config(command=self.Student_table.xview)
        scrolly.config(command=self.Student_table.yview)
        self.Student_table.heading("Roll", text="Roll No.")
        self.Student_table.heading("Name", text="Name")
        self.Student_table.heading("Email", text="Email")
        self.Student_table.heading("Gender", text="Gender")
        self.Student_table.heading("Contact", text="Contact")
        self.Student_table.heading("dob", text="D.O.B")
        self.Student_table.heading("Address", text="Address")

        self.Student_table['show']='headings'
        self.Student_table.column("Roll", width=100)
        self.Student_table.column("Name", width=100)
        self.Student_table.column("Email", width=100)
        self.Student_table.column("Gender", width=100)
        self.Student_table.column("Contact", width=100)
        self.Student_table.column("dob", width=100)
        self.Student_table.column("Address", width=150)
        self.Student_table.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    def on_all(self):
        for child in self.Manage_Frame.winfo_children():
            child.configure(state='normal')

    def off_all(self):
        for child in self.Manage_Frame.winfo_children():
            child.configure(state='disabled')



root = Tk()
st = Students(root)
root.mainloop()
```

In this part I'm getting the error.

```
    def on_all(self):
        for child in self.Detail_Frame.winfo_children():
            child.configure(state='normal')

    def off_all(self):
        for child in self.Detail_Frame.winfo_children():
            child.configure(state='disabled')
```

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Manish Gusain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Manish Gusain/PycharmProjects/Student_Management_System.py", line 233, in off_all
    child.configure(state='disabled')
  File "C:\Users\Manish Gusain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1485, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Manish Gusain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1476, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-state"
```

What I'm trying to do is when I click the Off button all the widgets in the frame should be disabled & when I click On button all the widgets in the frame should be enabled again. But when I click the Off button or On Button it shows this error.

Secondly, how to hide everything except the heading in the tkinter main window when hide button is clicked and show everything again when show button is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning your two issues:

- The Frame object has no `state` attribute so you can check if the widget is a frame and skip the update. You can also use a try\except block to catch errors. The below code does both.
- To hide the main frame, just move it off screen so it's not visible on the form

Here is the updated code. You will need to add `self` to the `Table_Frame` references so it is accessible in the on\off methods.

```
    self.Table_Frame = Frame(self.root, bd=4, relief=RIDGE, bg="crimson")  # chnge to self.Table_Frame
    self.Table_Frame.place(x=500,y=110, width=760, height=500)

    scrollx = Scrollbar(self.Table_Frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    scrolly = Scrollbar(self.Table_Frame, orient=VERTICAL)
    self.Student_table = ttk.Treeview(self.Table_Frame, columns=("Roll", "Name", "Email", "Gender", "Contact", "dob", "Address"), xscrollcommand=scrollx.set, yscrollcommand=scrolly.set)

.............

def on_all(self):
    self.Table_Frame.place(x=500,y=110, width=760, height=500)  # on screen
    for child in self.Manage_Frame.winfo_children():
        try:
            if child.widgetName != 'frame':  # frame has no state, so skip
               child.configure(state='normal')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

def off_all(self):
    self.Table_Frame.place(x=5000,y=110, width=760, height=500)  # off screen
    for child in self.Manage_Frame.winfo_children():
        try:
            if child.widgetName != 'frame':  # frame has no state, so skip
                child.configure(state='disabled')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Output (On)

[image: On]

Output (Off)

[image: Off]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mike67, it's working exactly the way I wanted. Could you clear my doubts please. 
**1**. Why my code`for child in self.Detail_Frame.winfo_children():     child.configure(state='disabled')` is showing error.

**2**. What's the logic behind your code of enable/disable widgets inside a frame. Please explain in simple terms as I'm new to python.

Comment: The error occurs when you try to set the `state` property of a Frame which has no state property. Only labels\buttons\entries has a state property. In this case, the code checks if the object is a frame. If it is, the code does not try to set the state property.

Comment: Thank you so much @Mike67 for your help. I appreciate it.