# Disable tkinter checkbuttons when a button is pressed

Tags: python, tkinter, button, checkbox, disable

I am working with Tkinter and I am trying to use some checkbuttons.

Here's what I am doing:

1. get a list with some ingredients
2. get a tkinter GUI with some checkbuttons (one for each ingredient)
3. select some of the checkbuttons (tick them)
4. press a button and obtain a list containing the ingredients I selected

What I am trying to do now is the following:

5. make the checkbuttons unusable (so, disable them) after the "confirmation" button is pressed.

My code is from the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72176078/tkinter-get-checkbuttons-checked) of my other question (I did not make much further progress in the checkbuttons of my application). I report it below:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk() 
INGREDIENTS = ['cheese', 'ham', 'pickle', 'mustard', 'lettuce'] 
txt = tk.Text(root, width=40, height=20) 
variables = [] 
for i in INGREDIENTS: 
    variables.append( tk.IntVar( value = 0 ) ) 
    cb = tk.Checkbutton( txt, text = i, variable = variables[-1] ) 
    txt.window_create( "end", window=cb ) 
    txt.insert( "end", "\n" ) 
txt.pack() 
 
def read_ticks():  
    result = [ ing for ing, cb in zip( INGREDIENTS, variables ) if cb.get()>0 ] 
    print( result ) 
  
but = tk.Button( root, text = 'Read', command = read_ticks) 
but.pack()  
  
root.mainloop()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: how-to-disable-and-enable-all-widgets-in-a-python-tkinter-frame : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64080833/how-to-disable-and-enable-all-widgets-in-a-python-tkinter-frame

Comment: Hi @Claudio. So I have to put ```state='disabled'```, but where should I put it? I tried but it returns me an error for ```IntVar```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below a solution based on remembering references to the checkbuttons in a list, but it should be also possible to get these references by querying all of the children of root excluding the tk.Button from being disabled.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk() 
INGREDIENTS = ['cheese', 'ham', 'pickle', 'mustard', 'lettuce'] 
txt = tk.Text(root, width=40, height=20) 
variables = []
buttons   = []

for i in INGREDIENTS: 
    variables.append( tk.IntVar( value = 0 ) ) 
    cb = tk.Checkbutton( txt, text = i, variable = variables[-1] )
    buttons.append(cb)
    txt.window_create( "end", window=cb ) 
    txt.insert( "end", "\n" ) 
txt.pack() 
 
def read_ticks():  
    result = [ ing for ing, cb in zip( INGREDIENTS, variables ) if cb.get()>0 ] 
    print( result )
    for button in buttons:
        button.config(state = 'disabled')
            
  
but = tk.Button( root, text = 'Read', command = read_ticks) 
but.pack()  
  
root.mainloop()
```